Order table by collection value
I'm using PostgreSQL with Dapper.
My situation that I have 2 tables, GamePlayCount and Game from 2 databases (difference connection string) .
First thing I select the most rating game like I have Count and GameId (data type is Guid).
Then at the table Game, I want to order by like Count of the GameId. The data will like
ListGameIdCountResponse { Count = 1, GameId = 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx' }

Then I make the ListGameIdCount into the string like this
var ListGameIdCount = string.Join(',', ListGameIdCountResponse.Select(p => $"('{p.GameId}',{p.Count})").ToList()); 

Example:
ListGameIdCount =  ('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx',10),('xxxxx-bbbb-xxxx',9)

So the query get trending game will like:
var query= @"SELECT  g."Name",g."Id"                           
FROM  "Games" g
LEFT JOIN (VALUES @GameIdList) as TrendingGameCount (GameId,Count) 
ON g.""Id"" = TrendingGameCount.GameId ::uuid
ORDER BY TrendingGame.Count DESC";

After that I use dapper to query
conn.Query(query, new { @GameIdList= ListGameIdCount})

The problem im facing now after binding the ListGameIdCount into the query it have double quote at the value
Example
LEFT JOIN (VALUES "('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx',1))" as TrendingGameCount (GameId,Count) 

What I want is
LEFT JOIN (VALUES ('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx',1)) as TrendingGameCount (GameId,Count) 

I try to replace or trim the double quote before binding data into query but it not work

It has really simple answer, but to correct it, put REAL var query= SELECT code, not something non-compilable.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv so what the answer is

Use string.Replace. You cannot use parameters here. something like this query = query.Replace(“@GameIdList”, ListGameIdCount.ToString() )
